# Adding to cart quantity Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to update the quantity on my cart but it doesn't actually update the quantity. My cart is model based but I think the problem line is here:

```
product_obj['quantity'] += 1
```

I get an error:
'Product' object is not subscriptable

My views.py

```
def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')

    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("Show message to user, product is gone?")
            return redirect("cart:home")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
            product_obj['quantity'] += 1

    return redirect("cart:home")
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you just use (assuming product_obj is not an actual list or dictionary) ...

```
product_obj.quantity += 1
```

Comment: We need to save the object after updating the value. Add `product_obj.save()`.